# Exchanging data between Java and C# application

Tags: java, c#

Beside using the socket, is there any better way we can use to exchange data between those two types of applications. They will always run on the same machine.

Thank you.

Comment: [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/cross-language-clients.html)?

Comment: You can even use Apache Kafka.

Comment: Depending on the scenario WCF might be an option too.

Comment: Using a flat file and protect access to it with the same Mutex in both application also comes to mind.

Depends on the nature/size of the data you want to interchange.

Comment: Another option is to use a message broker; like ActiveMQ

Comment: First of all we need to know how much data? What kind of data? How often do you want data exchange? Is it based on schedule or on request ?

Comment: the data is not large, only a few bytes, data is generated bases on requests, the sending/receiving order is important

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate a Rest service that hold data in a queue, then clears the queue after the data is  retrieved.